# Only Name File with Extension in Windows

Tags: windows, linux, file

I am trying to create a file in Windows XP that is **only** the extension (".classpath" and ".project").  While my Linux box handles this appropriately, Windows gives me the error, "You must type a file name."

Any suggestions how to do this?  I am attempting to setup an Eclipse project where I can bring in the classpath and project files from someone else's setup and I keep getting the above error.

Comment: Not sure if it matters but this will be a "hidden" file in linux.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

use the commandline to do this, windows explorer doesn’t allow renamed files to start with a period. first create the file/directory with a dummy name x.ext, then fire up cmd.exe and rename it:

```
ren x.ext .ext
```

this way you can also create directories which names start with a period (like .git or .meta)

Comment: 20+ years of working with DOS and it's kid brother, Windows, and this is the first I ever heard of this. Sheesh, there's ALWAYS something new.

Comment: i never knew you couldn't change to a dot name in explorer either

Answer (score 39):

Just name your file with additional dot at the end: ".ext."
explorer will remove additional dot and you'll get .ext file.

Comment: WOW! Awesome solution. I never knew this!

Comment: Awesome. Worked for me in Windows 7.

Comment: This is totally a bug that's being used as a feature. I love software development :)

Answer (score 1):

From the command line:

```
echo some text > .classpath
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows seems not to be in control of how Save dialogs handle forbidden characters

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the filename should do the job.

I have no Windows machine to try it out but I was able to save a ".htaccess" file in Notepad this way.

Comment: No Dice, it doesn't like the quote characters either... See http://superuser.com/a/406758/141104